# Change function in Jquery on change of dropdown

Tags: jquery

I tried this. but its not working, on change of dropdown i want to read values of drop down

```
$('.dropDown').change(function(){

    var valueOfsectotList=$(this).attr('data-value');
    $('#sectorValue').val(valueOfsectotList);
    loadFilters(valueOfsectotList);
});
```

`enter code here`

Comment: please share your html for the dropdown

Comment: $('.dropDown') you are using the class for drop down so may be you have more then one drop down in your html and if you have only one the use some DOM id instead of class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the attribute `data-value` of your selected option, you can change:

```
var valueOfsectotList=$(this).attr('data-value');
```

to:

```
var valueOfsectotList=$(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using    `.val()` function can get you the value of select option
use
`var valueOfsectotList=$(this).val();`

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a working example. You can change the controls names and condition as you require before using it.

First add the DropDown control like this.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCustomerType" runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="dropdown" DataValueField="Name" DataTextField="ID" OnChange="ShowCustomerDetails();"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

Fill the ddlCustomerType and make sure that its ValueField contains a value as 'LOCAL'

Then add the Script part. It should work within the given conditions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPaymentSection()
    {
        var ddlCustomerType= document.getElementById('<%=ddlCustomerType.ClientID%>');
        if (ddlCustomerType.value == 'LOCAL') 
        {
            //Code here
        }
    }
</script>
```